# Counting vowels

Tags: python

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this script. I am a python newb but i cant seem to figure out what might be causing it not to function.

```
def find_vowels(sentence):

    """
    >>> find_vowels(test)
    1

    """

    count = 0
    vowels = "aeiuoAEIOU"
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter in vowels:
            count += 1
    print count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Well for one thing, you forgot 'u'

Comment: Didnt pay much attention. You are right

Comment: Your tabulation seems a little off to me. Does it look the same on your source file?

Comment: Yes copied from eclipse/pydev ide.

Comment: @gnibbler It's maybe not the best idea to change the indentation while we're establishing if it's one of the problems in his code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the fact that you're returning a count but expecting a string of vowels, as others have said, you must also change the line

```
>>> find_vowels(test)
```

to

```
>>> find_vowels('test')
```

You forgot the quotes!

Comment: Then you could consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark icon below the big number on the question's upper left) and (once you've got the extra rep that comes from accepting, which puts you above the threshold for being able to upvote) upvoting (clicking the triangle above the already-mentioned big number).  Basic SO etiquette: thanks are nice and all, but accepts and upvotes are what makes SO go around!-)

Answer (score 8):

You're printing `count` (a number), but your test expects the letter `e`.

Also, the more Pythonic way to count the vowels would be a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> len([letter for letter in 'test' if letter in vowels])
1
```

Want to *see* the vowels you've found?  Just drop that leading `len` function:

```
>>> [letter for letter in 'stackoverflow' if letter in vowels]
['a', 'o', 'e', 'o']
```

Comment: -1 building a LIST of vowels just to count them is not "pythonic" ... consider `sum(letter in vowels for letter in test)` AND vowels should be a set, not list.

Comment: @John: Valid point on the counting, but I disagree in regards to using a set.  From what we know about the specifications (nothing), should `find_vowels('wheel')` return `'e'` or `['e', 'e']`?  I assumed it was the latter.

Comment: I meant "vowels should be a set, not sequence" i.e. set("aeiouAEIOU") not "aeiouAEIOU" ... `vowels` is used to check the INPUT (`letter in vowels`) of both a count function and a "find" function; it's nothing to do with the OUTPUT from a "find" function.

Answer (score 1):

Your test expects the function to print the vowels it found, but you're printing the count instead. You're also passing it the variable `test` instead of the string `'test'`, you need to do

```
>>> find_vowels('test')
```

Finally, the indenting is off, but I assume that was a pasting problem

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_vowels(word):
'''
str->(number)
returns the number of vowels used
count_vowels('ramesh')
>>>2
count_vowels('sindhu')
>>>2
'''

vowels=list('a,e,i,o,u')
return vowels.count(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the body of find_vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **str.count()**
For example
s='heeello world'

> > > print str.count(s,'e')
> > >       3

Answer (score 0):

This solution is pretty clean, and more efficient than the solutions already posted for large strings; the hard work all happens in the C-loop of constructing the Counter object.

```
from collections import Counter
vowels = "aeiuoAEIOU"

def count_vowels(txt):
    c = Counter(txt)
    return sum(c[v] for v in vowels)

print count_vowels('testing')
```